# How to redact sensitive information from log4net?

Tags: .net, log4net

Some exception messages in our application contain credentials/private keys or other sensitive information which should not make it into the error log.  I would like to filter the content of the logged message before it is written so that known sensitive values and/or patterns can be replaced with [redacted] or some such text value.  A few searches haven't turned up anything.  Is there any way to do this and apply it in a generic way to all configured appenders?

I do not want to have to filter by knowing where all these exceptions may occur and writing exception handlers for this purpose.  The exceptions are not being thrown by our code, so "not doing that" is not an option.

Comment: Have you considered writing a custom log4net filter? Perhaps base it on StringMatchFilter? I'm unsure if filters can change the output, but you can at least use it to filter out the entries from the log.

Comment: I got the impression that filters are for including/excluding the entire event, not filtering the content.  There is useful information in there too, I just want to blank out the naughty bits

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: don't put them there in the first place.

Sure, you could make up some regexes and heuristics etc and run them periodically on your log - all these will be prone to failure or sabotage.

And there is NO reason whatsoever to have passwords and private keys in logs

Comment: I would never do so. These are not my application's exceptions, they are being thrown from third party libraries.

Comment: If that's the case just skip the logging of the entire exception at the sensitive spots. Whatever you do, make sure the sensitive information never reaches the log file rather than trying to redact it later

Comment: Well, that's the goal.  I would rather do something at the log4net level to install a filter rather than trying to find all the places in code this may happen.

Comment: you could write a custom filter and you could configure it and all that - still not good enough to guarantee the security of your log. it would still be possible to modify the config file and get sensitive data recorded in plaintext. Despite filtering being possible it's not a good idea

Comment: I'm not concerned about the security of the config file.

Comment: @jlew then you're not concerned with security altogether and you might as well keep logging the sensitive bits - chances are they live on the same server as your config file and having access to one is likely equivalent to having access to the other

Answer (score 0):

I would expect (but haven't tried it) that you could write a `BufferingAppender` based on the [sample here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Appender/BufferingAppenderSkeleton.cs?view=markup) and could use the method `override protected void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)` to change the logingEvent to remove the sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that.  I was hoping that there is something that can be applied uniformly to multiple existing appenders, but I'm losing hope.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option.

Since the "offending" code is a third party library, you are correct that you can't simply "remove the information from the exception".

However, you could create a Facade class for calling that library with the same API, and then add Error Handling/redaction into the new class.  Then simply use that class in place of the original library throughout your code.